# Merge 2 PHP array using the keys from 1 array and values from another with the exception that if the key does not exist in one if has to be removed

Tags: php, arrays

I am tring to take 2 PHP arrays which hold PLugin data.

1 array has plugin key/values from database and the other is from plugin file headers

I need to create a new array that merges the values from the file array into the db array.

If the db array has a key that does not exist in the file array, that key should be removed from the final array.

If the file array has a key that does not exist in the db array, it should remain in the file array.

The final array output goal is to make sure the new array always has all the keys that exist in the DB array and those keys have values that are from matching keys in the file array.

---

**New Array:**

**keys** = from DB array.  If the File array is missing a key from the DB array, remove it from the new array.

**values** = from the File array where the DB array key matches the array key in File array, then return that value for the new array.

---

I have tested using PHP's `array_merge`, `array_replace`, and `array_intersect_keys`.  There code and output are shown below...

`array_intersect_keys` get the closest to my desired result but it does not remove keys that exist in DB array and are not present in the file array.

```
// array_merge()
$dbPluginArray = array(
    'version' => '',
    'name' => 'db-name',
    'db-key-not-exist-in-file-array' => '' // this key should be removed from the final array
);
$filePluginArray = array(
    'version' => 'file-version',
    'name' => 'file-name',
    'file-key-not-exist-in-db-array' => 'trapezoid'
);
$newMergeArray = array_merge($dbPluginArray, $filePluginArray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newMergeArray );
echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [version] => file-version
    [name] => file-name
    [db-key-not-exist-in-file-array] => 
    [file-key-not-exist-in-db-array] => trapezoid
)
*/


// array_replace()
$dbPluginArray = array(
    'version' => '',
    'name' => 'db-name',
    'db-key-not-exist-in-file-array' => '' // this key should be removed from the final array
);
$filePluginArray = array(
    'version' => 'file-version',
    'name' => 'file-name',
    'file-key-not-exist-in-db-array' => 'trapezoid'
);
$newReplaceArray  = array_replace($dbPluginArray, $filePluginArray);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newReplaceArray);
echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [version] => file-version
    [name] => file-name
    [db-key-not-exist-in-file-array] => 
    [file-key-not-exist-in-db-array] => trapezoid
)
*/





// array_intersect_key
$dbPluginArray = array(
    'version' => '',
    'name' => 'db-name',
    'db-key-not-exist-in-file-array' => '', // this key should be removed from the final array,
    'test' => 'testval'
);
$filePluginArray = array(
    'version' => 'file-version',
    'name' => 'file-name',
    'file-key-not-exist-in-db-array' => 'trapezoid',
    'test' => 'testval'
);
echo '<pre>';
$result = array_intersect_key($filePluginArray,$dbPluginArray);
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

/*
Array
(
    [version] => file-version
    [name] => file-name
    [test] => testval
)
*/
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the `array_*` functions won't do the job and that you might have to program something yourself?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Actually that is what I do 95% of the time and then people post a PHP array function that accomplishes the same task I did....so for once I was trying to put the built in functions to use to try and learn them more as I never really use them!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
$dbPluginArray = array(
    'version' => '',
    'name' => 'db-name',
    'db-key-not-exist-in-file-array' => '' // this key should be removed from the final array
);
$filePluginArray = array(
    'version' => 'file-version',
    'name' => 'file-name',
    'file-key-not-exist-in-db-array' => 'trapezoid'
);
echo '<pre>';
$result = array_merge(array_intersect_key($filePluginArray,$dbPluginArray), $filePluginArray);
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [version] => file-version
    [name] => file-name
    [file-key-not-exist-in-db-array] => trapezoid
)
*/

$dbPluginArray = array(
    'version' => '',
    'name' => 'db-name',
    'db-key-not-exist-in-file-array' => '', // this key should be removed from the final array,
    'test' => 'testval'
);
$filePluginArray = array(
    'version' => 'file-version',
    'name' => 'file-name',
    'file-key-not-exist-in-db-array' => 'trapezoid',
    'test' => 'testval'
);
echo '<pre>';
$result = array_merge(array_intersect_key($filePluginArray,$dbPluginArray), $filePluginArray);
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
/*
Array
(
    [version] => file-version
    [name] => file-name
    [test] => testval
    [file-key-not-exist-in-db-array] => trapezoid
)
*/
```

Comment: for array_intersect_keys. But $dbPluginArray should be at first?

Comment: for being the FIRST with the most elegant solution.. which was later used as a rip-off in the answer below :)

Comment: @NabinKunwar What will be difference if $dbPluginArray is first ??

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job too. using `foreach` and `arry_merge`

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($dbPluginArray as $key=>$val){
    if(array_key_exists($key,$filePluginArray)){
        $newArray[$key]=$val;
    }
}

$finalArray = array_merge($newArray,$filePluginArray);
print_r($finalArray);
```

For better solution suggested below using [array_intersect_kay](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

Comment: I missed below word. :D

Comment: That is perfect...I just realized I made a mistake as if the key in file array does not exist in the DB array, then it should also be removed!  that might of made it easiar to start with even, thanks for helping

Comment: @JasonDavis Yah. I also thought about logical way than builtin way.